# Is "or" defined differently for Mathematica and Mathics?

Tags: mathics

In Mathematica, "or" looks to be defined with a double vertical bar.  See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119763.

In Mathics 2.1.0, that doesn't seem to work:

```
In[16]:= If[1<0 || 2<3 || 3<4, 0, 1]
Syntax::sntxf: "If[1<0 " cannot be followed by " 2<3  3<4, 0, 1]" (line 1 of "<stdin>").
```

whereas the word "or" seems to work:

```
In[16]:= If[1<0 or 2<3 or 3<4, 0, 1]
Out[16]= 1
```

So do I have to use `||` in Mathematica and `or` in Mathics, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Mathics has a documentation, though it's a pdf for some reason, https://mathics.org/docs/mathics-latest.pdf

Page 11 at the moment (part of ***3. Language Tutorials***):

> ***Comparisons and Boolean Logic***
>
> [...]
>
> Truth values can be negated using ! (logical not) and combined using && (logical and) and || (logical or):
>
> ```
> >> !True
>    False
> >> !False
>    True
> >> 3 < 4 && 6 > 5
>    True
> ```
>
> && has higher precedence than ||, i.e. it binds stronger:
>
> ```
> >> True && True || False && False
>    True
> >> True && (True || False) && False
>    False
> ```

based on that I would indeed expect `||` and `&&` to work.

Also, there is an example on page 44 with `If[x == 0.0 && y <= 0, 0.0, Sin[x ^ y] + 1 / Min[x, 0.5]] + 0.5]`.

Your error message may be the key here as the `||` became those boxed question marks, which may be something about character encoding. If it is a file you are running, it may be worth checking if it's ASCII.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I thought about encoding. But, I just typed it in at my keyboard (into `mathicsscript`), totally normal pipe characters: `||`. It's definitely ASCII.

Comment: Perhaps you could try it?

Comment: @dfrankow it works for me, however the version is very different, conda-forge installed only 1.1.1 to me.